# Detect browser upgrade availability?

Tags: browser, version

So one thing I'm tired of is people not updating their browsers. This is especially problematic in CSS, because I have to duplicate, triplicate or... quadruplicate?... a lot of CSS3 rules to add vendor prefixes.

I'd like to know if there's any way to detect whether a browser update is available. Preferably without maintaining a database of latest versions, however I realise that may be the only option.

If there is no easy "isUpdateAvailable" flag, I suppose I can keep track of "minimum supported versions" for IE, Firefox and Chrome, at least, and I guess the `navigator` object can help check it. Any pointers there?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service like http://browser-update.org to detect and remind visitors to upgrade their browser if it's out-of-date.

Essentially the service has you insert some JavaScript into your page, and upon page load, your visitor's browser will use the service to determine if their browser is out-of-date and then show an upgrade message if applicable.